# What, if anything, can I do to recover bitcoin that was stolen from my MtGox acct in June, 2013?

Tags: blockchain, mtgox

I understand the short answer is "nothing", but I ask because I've had trouble explaining this to a coworker which made me realize I don't really get it myself.

What information can I glean from following the stolen bitcoin on a blockchain explorer?  1GvfmXt2CKP8QJfw93LNcnNV6KghD5ohVA

How useful is the IP address the withdrawal was made from? IP: 75.110.224.12

Do I have any legal recourse when the company in question is bankrupt, in Japan, and the theft occurred almost five years ago?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that can be done with just a public address and an IP(as the real IP is most likely behind proxy/vpn/etc...).

[Kraken](https://blog.kraken.com/post/267/mt-gox-bankruptcy/) was selected by the MtGox trustee to assist MtGox creditors in investigating missing Bitcoin, filing claims, and distributing remaining assets.
The due date for accepting MtGox creditor claims via online submission has past.
[But creditors may still be able to submit claims via the offline claims method.](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/204802478-How-can-I-process-my-MtGox-claim-with-Kraken-)

Comment: This hack happened before the bankruptcy. Can I learn anything from following the movement of the bitcoin after it was withdrawn? Anything at all?

Comment: Many have tried, example [Wizsec](http://blog.wizsec.jp), the conclusions are that the trails were obfuscated via mixing, laundering, or simply sold off for cash. [Trails become statistically impossible to trace after going through several Darknet tumblers and cross-chain tumblers.](https://www.reddit.com/r/DarkNetMarketsNoobs/wiki/bible/buyer/bitcoin/tumbling)